# Put actual date (dd/mm/yyyy) to a css variable with HTML

Tags: css, html

I have a variable DataTime named dataalta (public DateTime? dataalta { get; set; }), that I'll put on a database, and i want to introduce the actual date to it. But the create is on a html (this is a website), and I use @Html.EditorFor, and the user put it, but I want to use DateTime.UtcNow. How I can use it ? (im really new on this, sorry if is an stupid question)

Comment: does @Html.Raw(DateTime.UtcNow) work?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.wmtmediador.dataalta,  @Html.Raw(DateTime.UtcNow))
 this ?? i tried it and didn't work

Comment: The title is unclear. You don't really want to something with CSS variables.